# Rspec, the unexpect variable assign

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

In the controller, it doesn't assign any variable to view. But in Rspec test the variable always assigned.

orders#index

```
# GET /orders
# GET /orders.json
def index
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { render :app }
    # format.json { @orders = Order.all.order('created_at desc'); puts 'run'}
  end
end
```

orders_spec.rb

```
describe "GET #index" do
  it "assigns all orders as @orders" do
    order = Order.place_order valid_attributes
    puts order
    # get :index, format: :json
    # expect(assigns(:orders)).to eq([order])
    get :index, format: 'html'
    expect(assigns(:orders)).to eq(nil)
  end
end
```

result:

```
Failures:

1) OrdersController GET #index assigns all orders as @orders
   Failure/Error: expect(assigns(:orders)).to eq(nil)

     expected: nil
          got: #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Order id: 1, user_id: 1, price: #<BigDecimal:7f9e57da2f30,'0.999E3',9(27)>, created_at: "2015-09-28 04:44:10", updated_at: "2015-09-28 04:44:10", uid: "150928120001">]>

     (compared using ==)
   # ./spec/controllers/orders_controller_spec.rb:54:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Comment: Are you using cancan or pundit? Do you have any before filters in the orders controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somehow in your code, `orders` are getting populated for the `html` template. May be you have a `before_filter` or something else (e.g. `load_and_authorize_resource` in case you are using `cancancan`) that always assigns the `orders` irrespective of the format. Please make sure that's not the case.

Comment: Please see my updated answer. Its really hard to say without seeing the full application code. Could you please show us the full code of the controller?

Comment: I remove the `load_and_authorize_resource` of the Cancancan. `@orders == nil` now.